# How to specify the `-i` sudo option in a sudoers file for apt-get?

Tags: sudo

On my single-user workstation, I configured `sudoers(5)` so that some commands can be executed without password. Specifically, this is an example of an entry:

```
$ cat /etc/sudoers.d/apt-get 
my_user_name ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/apt-get
```

However, I need to run this command as `sudo -i apt-get install` (i.e., *with* the `-i` option).

Is that possible to somehow modify the configuration file, so that `-i` (or some other `sudo` option) would be implied even if I ran simply as `sudo apt-get install` (i.e., *without* `-i`)?

(The OS is Ubuntu 14.04, but I think this question is not specific to a particular Linux distro.)

Comment: You probably don't need a root login shell to run `apt-get install`. In other words, `sudo apt-get install` is enough so your `/etc/sudoers.d/apt-get` file should be good enough.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, I am not totally sure about that. Recently, I got `frontend 12089 IBUS-WARNING The owner of /home/my_user_name/.config/ibus/bus is not root!` message during `apt-get install` - that is why I've started to used `sudo -i`.

Comment: @AlexanderPozdneev for that, probably all you need is `always_set_home`. You don't actually need a login shell, just reset `$HOME` to root's home..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@muru](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/70524/muru) pointed out in a [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389714/how-to-specify-the-i-sudo-option-in-a-sudoers-file#comment694304_389714), the login shell (i.e., `sudo -i`) is not needed in this scenario (i.e., `sudo apt-get ...`). The `always_set_home` sudoers file option would be enough (it would reset `$HOME` to root's home).

The sudoers file entry should look like this:

```
$ sudo cat /etc/sudoers.d/apt-get
Defaults!/usr/bin/apt-get always_set_home
my_user_name ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/apt-get
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your interactive root shell is `/bin/bash` (but beware, maybe your `/etc/passwd` sets something else, e.g. `/bin/dash`).

Then what you really want is to run a root login shell from `sudo`. As I commmented, I believe you usually don't need that. And you could also unset some environment variables, or set them to appropriate defaults, thru your `/etc/sudoers.d/apt-get` file.

But [Invoking Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Invoking-Bash.html) says that

> `-l`
>
> > Make this shell act as if it had been directly invoked by login. When the shell is interactive, this is equivalent to starting a login shell with `exec -l bash`. When the shell is not interactive, the login shell startup files will be executed. `exec bash -l` or `exec bash --login` will replace the current shell with a Bash login shell. See Bash Startup Files, for a description of the special behavior of a login shell.

and later

> A login shell is one whose first character of argument zero is `-`, or one invoked with the `--login` option.

So you probably could write a shell script (or a wrapper program in C) which invokes `bash` with `-l` or `--login`, and have that thing mentioned in `/etc/sudoers.d/apt-get`

Perhaps running `/bin/bash -l -c "/usr/bin/apt-get $*"` could be enough.

Notice also that `sudoers(5)` mentions `env_reset` and `env_keep`

Maybe you want just to remove a few environment variables like `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` ....

<sup>(I could be wrong and never tried this)</sup>